# Laravel-dusk does not work

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

On working project, after installation of updates, I get errors with all dusk tests

```
 1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
  Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-81-generic x86_64)
```

I have already reinstalled dusk, updated composer and vagrant... And I have no any ideas how to update that dirver.

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and vagrant box on localhost. Chrome doesn't installed on the system.

Thanks for any advice..

Answer (score 4):

Well...
After couple hours of dancing and googling, I installed update on the virtual Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # Installs updates (new ones)
```

It changed the version of Chrome.
After, I changed in my domain name .dev to .test, because Chrome >63+ [forces .dev domains to HTTPS via preloaded HSTS](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/).

Comment: This worked for me also. I would expect that since I'm using the latest release of Laravel Homestead, it would work out of the box. Now I imagine if you replace the Chome driver with something else if it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install chrome driver for a different version, I had the same issue and this fixed:

```
php artisan dusk:chrome-driver 74
```